# Mobile navigation toggle won't work when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made navigation for smaller screen. When I click on menu toggle the menu will show. My problem is that: On my jsdiffle it works, but when I try it with my files on internet it won't work. Do I link the js file in wrong way?

I have my script in js folder and my file name is `mobile_nav.js`. 
I also have donwloaded `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` to js folder. It didn't work and I also tried to copy this link `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and added on my html.

Please see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/oh1bo03f/2/)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console of the browser?

Comment: I clicked on the menu and see no error. I am using Firefox, Firebug --> Console ---> Error I don't see any error.

Comment: Odd, figured there would be an error of some type. It must be related to resources somehow, is the site live and we can view it to look at it (since the Fiddle works)?

Comment: I'm sorry, the site is not live since I am still working with that menu.